# How to keep the array 'structure' inside a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

my question is, if I have an array in javascript, let's say :

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

And I want to transform it into a string that would look like this : y = "[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]", how should I do it?
I tried this things:

```
let a = x.toString();
let b = y.toLocaleString();
let c = new String(x);
```

But the problem with it is that, all of them look like this:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
```

So, it completely removes the '[]'.
How can I keep the array inside the string like this :

```
"[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]"
```

*with the []*

Comment: `JSON.stringify(x)` would yield `"[1,2,3,[4,5,6]]"`. The other methods also don’t include spaces after commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this helps?

```js
 let y = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]];
 

 var x = JSON.stringify(y);
 
 console.log(typeof(x));
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
```